# I am trying to add image as a props item img but its wont display

Tags: reactjs

Learning about props in react atm, I’m having an issue whereby when I try to pass an image as a prop its won’t display at all, see the screenshot below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcZNH.png)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const HeroSlider = (props) => {
  const data = props.data;

  return (
    <div className="hero-slider">
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <HeroSliderItem key={index} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

HeroSlider.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

const HeroSliderItem = (props) => (
  <div className="hero-slider__item">
    <div className="hero-slider__item__info">
      <div className="hero-slider__item__info__title">
        <span>{props.item.title}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="hero-slider__item__info__description">
        <span>{props.item.description}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="hero-slider__item__info__btn">
        <Link to={props.item.path}>
          <button>Shop Now</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="hero-slider__item__image">
      <img src={props.item.img} alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default HeroSlider;
```

[props data img from  my assets folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OvGz.png)

Comment: Where is this `prop` coming from ? Is it from some api call ? Add an example of prop data.

Comment: its an example of prop data

Comment: Still not clear whether the prop data is coming asynchronously from an api call or not. But you can try adding optional chaining where you are setting the src to an image. Just make it like this `props?.item?.img`.

Comment: added i have created this data in my assets folder by my hand its not a api

Comment: Did you try above optional chaining method ?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `item` into `HeroSliderItem` so you should fix your property path for Img Src:

```html
<img src={props.img} alt="" />
```

I recommend you rename the variable name of the parameter for your component to:

```js
const HeroSliderItem = (item) => (

);
```

So you can access the `.img` property in a more semantic way:

```html
<img src={item.img} alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store images in variables using images relative path and then use it in your heroSliderData object like bellow.

```
const img1 = "../Images/Slider/slide_1.png";
const img2 = "../Images/Slider/slide_2.png";
const img3 = "../Images/Slider/slide_3.png";

const heroSliderData = [
  //your objects here
]
```